# DevEx Report sorting throws an Error when clicking on different columns rapidly to change sort criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, devexpress, reporting, devexpress-mvc

I have this issue when trying to dynamically sort one of my reports. I have two columns/fields that I use for sorting, they work just fine if I am taking my time clicking on them, however, if I click on them rapidly - I am getting an error.

I feel like it's happening when I am trying to sort a report and while it's in process of sorting (it takes about 5 seconds) I'm clicking on different column headers trying to resort it while it's still loading.

The report is about 130 pages and I noticed that when I click on the column header to sort, the toolbar icons (printers and diskette) are being disabled until sorting is complete.

My question is: Can I disable sorting abilities of the column headers until the report finishes initial sorting? Or any alternate way to prevent this error to happened?

Thank you.

I know it's not really a coding question, but I couldn't fine any solution on the Internet. I submitted a ticket on devexpress.com but didn't get any response yet.

Answer (score -1):

It is difficult to say for sure why this behavior occurs.

However, updating to the latest version of DevExpress may be a potential solution.